# Url architecture / overriding defaults

Tags: python, django, url, django-registration

Linked to another post, I want to ask the best practice to organize my urls in my django project.

my main urls.py contain :

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.vince.urls')),
```

then, my registration.backends.vince.urls.py is :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^activate/complete/$',
                           TemplateView.as_view(template_name='registration/activation_complete.html'),
                           name='registration_activation_complete'),
                       # Activation keys get matched by \w+ instead of the more specific
                       # [a-fA-F0-9]{40} because a bad activation key should still get to the view;
                       # that way it can return a sensible "invalid key" message instead of a
                       # confusing 404.
                       url(r'^activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$',
                           ActivationView.as_view(),
                           name='registration_activate'),
                       url(r'^register/$',
                           RegistrationView.as_view(),
                           name='registration_register'),
                       url(r'^register/complete/$',
                           TemplateView.as_view(template_name='registration/registration_complete.html'),
                           name='registration_complete'),
                       url(r'^register/closed/$',
                           TemplateView.as_view(template_name='registration/registration_closed.html'),
                           name='registration_disallowed'),
                       (r'', include('registration.auth_urls')),
                       )
```

And my registration.auth_urls is:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^login/$',
                           auth_views.login,
                           {'template_name': 'registration/login.html'},
                           name='auth_login'),
                       url(r'^logout/$',
                           auth_views.logout,
                           {'template_name': 'registration/logout.html'},
                           name='auth_logout'),
                       url(r'^password/change/$',
                           auth_views.password_change,
                           name='auth_password_change'),
                       url(r'^password/change/done/$',
                           auth_views.password_change_done,
                           name='auth_password_change_done'),
                       url(r'^password/reset/$',
                           auth_views.password_reset,
                           {'template_name': 'registration/password_reset_form2.html'},
                           name='auth_password_reset'),
                       url(r'^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',
                           auth_views.password_reset_confirm,
                           name='auth_password_reset_confirm'),
                       url(r'^password/reset/complete/$',
                           auth_views.password_reset_complete,
                           name='auth_password_reset_complete'),
                       url(r'^password/reset/done/$',
                           auth_views.password_reset_done,
                           name='auth_password_reset_done'),
)
```

What I don't understand is I have to rename my templates in registration/templates to avoid displaying the django's admin templates. That's why I have a "password_reset_form2.html". But if I have a "password_reset_form.html", I will get the default admin password reset form.

One suggested I use namespacing, but I don't know exactly what to do.

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess here and say that the template loaders are finding the "registration/password_reset_form.html" that's provided by django.contrib.admin.templates.registration first before it finds yours (probably because the django package is in your path first before your django app), why don't you just rename your template registration directory?

Comment: Yes, that would be a solution. But I'm trying to understand how django is resolving my urls/templates system, can you write a response?

Comment: Actually I was wrong, it most likely has nothing to do with the system path ordering. Django loads templates according the template loaders that's defined in your settings, by default it has two: "filesystem" loader and "app_directories". app_directories will look in each app for templates and it will look in each app in the order that's defined by INSTALLED_APPS. Try moving the admin app lower in the chain of your apps to render your template first.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader